# add select all option for multiselect product attribute Magento

Tags: magento, attributes, product, multi-select, selectall

Hi i have a created a new product attribute with

> multi-select type

in that there are many select values.

> There are some products which has all those values

and

> those all needs to select manually

. So what i am looking for is to

> provide a option to select all options at once

. Can you please suggest me how can i do this.

thanks

Comment: Is this a programming-related question?

Comment: yes because by default there is no option in magento to define this but i am wonder how i can do this because we can create the attributes dynamically

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select all values in front side then you can use javascript is best way to select values. but if you want to give select option in admin side then you need to develop code.